# how add the external Stripe library to my symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to use Stripe with my Symfony projet. I have to add a php library.

To do that I use composer. I added to my composer.json:

```
"stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
```

Then I have to add:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

To my Default controller, but it seems not to work.

Adding that next the uses of the controller, the error says:

```
Compile Error: main(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

I think I miss something, but what?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: Symfony is already using the composer autoloader, you can just use the classes after installing the lib. Please note that there are several existing Symfony bundles available that integrate with Stripe. Using one of those will be easier than integrating it properly into Symfony yourself

Comment: I note that it has some other bundles, but now that I have done all myself, I would finish that. So I will learn how that work... I juste have to add this library and the rest must work. Do you now how I can do that?

Comment: You can look at one or more of the bundles to see how it's implemented. It's a bit more work than.installing the lib to get a proper bundle up and running